# "Can't import the Python Imaging Library"

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I have downloaded the `uniconvertor` to convert from `cdr` to `svg` on Debian 10 (which has no more this package, so I have to download from source). Now when trying to execute:

`$uniconv image.cdr image.svg`, I got this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/uniconvertor/__init__.py", line 64, in <module>
    from app.io import load
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/uniconvertor/app/__init__.py", line 62, in <module>
    from conf.configurator import Configurator
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/uniconvertor/app/conf/configurator.py", line 11, in <module>
    frm app.events import connector
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/uniconvertor/app/__init__.py", line 114, in <module>
    _import_PIL()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/uniconvertor/app/__init__.py", line 103, in _import_PIL
    warn.warn(warn.USER, "Can't import the Python Imaging Library")
NameError: global name 'warn' is not defined
```

Seems I have not "Imaging Library" and get error `NameError: global name 'warn' is not defined`, does it mean the function `warn` is not defined in that script?

Comment: The `warnings` package just needed to be imported.

Answer (score 1):

It seems your app needs Python `PIL` library to work but you don't have it installed. Try installing it https://pypi.org/project/Pillow/.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to follow two steps.

1. `import warnings` in your python file
2. Install pillow, PIL is Dead. Use Pillow `pip install Pillow`.