# Is uniconvertor application broken for debian 10?

Tags: python, image, svg, python-imaging-library

From my previous question: ["Can't import the Python Imaging Library"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63671373/cant-import-the-python-imaging-library/63671735#63671735), I am still trying to convert `cdr` file to `svg` file, and the only solution I find for Debian is to use `uniconvertor`. So for the first time, I was missing the Pillow library (`pip install Pillow`). When tried to run for the second time, another error arose:

```
$uniconv image.cdr image.svg
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/uniconvertor/__init__.py", line 76, in <module>
    saver(doc, sys.argv[2])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/uniconvertor/app/plugins/plugins.py", line 201, in __call__
    module.save(document, file, filename, options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/uniconvertor/app/plugins/Filters/svgsaver.py", line 299, in save
    saver.Save()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/uniconvertor/app/plugins/Filters/svgsaver.py", line 259, in Save
    left, bottom, right, top = self.document.BoundingRect()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'BoundingRect'
```

But this time I would have to edit (with no python knowledge) the `__init__.py` script (main). So I am assuming the whole application is broken? How to fix it, or is there another package to make the conversion (`cdr`->`svg`)?

Comment: That would be a start of a bug report but not a programming question for SO. Check for updated versions (possibly installed with pip instead), then check the bug trackers. If you really want to turn this into a programming question, you'd probably have to extract a [mcve] first.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I am just asking if this is real bug, or just happened to me. Otherwise you are right, I would not post it in SO if it is canonical bug of that software

Comment: You may find `inkscape` can read them. I presume you mean **Corel Draw** files?

Comment: @MarkSetchell I did. That's what `cdr` extension stands for -> Corel Draw picture